# Will most battery-powered smoke detectors attach to other back plates?

Tags: smoke-detectors

Need to replace a battery powered detector.  Do most of them have the same sort of back plate or will I generally have to attach a new back plate?  Do they usually come with a back plate?

Comment: Back plates are usually different between brands, but they all come with back plates anyway.  Might save a couple minutes if getting same brand.

Comment: No, they're not standardized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they come with a back plate, if you get the same brand (if still available) they might fit. But you'll get all the stuff you need to install them as it were a first time install.